# Add a product refers to one-or-many distributors in Magento

Tags: magento

I am using `Magento` to build a bookshop

A book includes:

- has many attributes such as: name, prices, weight, etc...
- belong to one publisher
- belong to one-or-many categories
- has many `distributors` which includes many attributes:

  - name
  - address
  - phone/email

So, when I create a book in Admin Management Panel, how I could:

1. Make a list of `distributors`.
2. Add a book (product) refer to
   one-or-many `distributors`?

Comment: Magento administration and operations questions are not on-topic on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a multiselect attribute called distributors. This will give you the possibility of adding one or multiple distributors to products. However, the attribute options only have IDs, label fields, and nothing else.

To extend this, you will need to write you own module with a database table containing your fields and a reference to the attribute option:

- Distributor ID (reference to option_id in eav_attribute_option)
- Name
- Address
- Phone
- Email

You will probably also need to write a backend interface for editing this data, and some functions to access distributor data by attribute option ID etc.

Comment: @Rasmussen: Can you give me a link with the tutorial about these?

Comment: Try this one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table